# how does a wireless printer identify itself on the network?

Tags: printing, wifi, wireless

For example, how does Windows know that a device on the network is a wireless printer?  What are the standards being used?

Are there generic protocols an application can use to submit print jobs to a such a printer if there is no available printer driver?

Comment: your question is off topic....

Comment: okay, excuse me for not being more precise.  I'm doing research for an application I'm writing that needs to identify itself as a printer on a network.  That's programming related.  I'm trying to understand what standards are involved so that I can write code to implement them.

Comment: @Tom I'd probably rephrase your question and title then to indicate eg what language you're writing in, and the fact that you want to know how you can announce your application as a network printer programmatically.

Comment: How about everyone just pile on and tell me how to correctly use stackoverflow?  Clearly that's what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Printing Protocol - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol

HP ePrint and Apple AirPrint appear to be protocols for driverless printing but I'm not fully clear on these.